# How to filter spark dataframe with URL exists or not?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter my spark dataframe. In this dataframe, there is an col of URL.

I have tried to use `os.path.exists(col("url"))` to filter my dataframe, but I got errors like

> "string is needed, but column has been found".

here is part of my code, pandas has been used in codes, and now i want to use spark to implement the following code

```
bob_ross = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("/dbfs/mnt/umsi-data-science/si618wn2017/bob_ross.csv")
bob_ross['image'] = ""
# create a column for each of the 85 colors (these will be c0...c84)
# we'll do this in a separate table for now and then merge
cols = ['c%s'%i for i in np.arange(0,85)]
colors = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
colors['EPISODE'] = bob_ross.index.values
colors = colors.set_index('EPISODE')

# figure out if we have the image or not, we don't have a complete set
for s in bob_ross.index.values:
    b = bob_ross.loc[s]['TITLE']
    b = b.lower()
    b = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9\s]', '',b)
    b = re.sub(r'\s', '_',b)
    img = b+".png"
    if (os.path.exists("/dbfs/mnt/umsi-data-science/si618wn2017/images/"+img)):
        bob_ross.set_value(s,"image","/dbfs/mnt/umsi-data-science/si618wn2017/images/"+img)
        t = getColors("/dbfs/mnt/umsi-data-science/si618wn2017/images/"+img)
        colors.loc[s] = t

bob_ross = bob_ross.join(colors)
bob_ross = bob_ross[bob_ross.image != ""]
```

here is how i try to implement it with spark, i am stuck at the error line

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
bob_ross = spark.read.csv('/mnt/umsi-data-science/si618wn2017/bob_ross.csv',header=True)
bob_ross=bob_ross.withColumn("image",concat(lit("/dbfs/mnt/umsi-data-science/si618wn2017/images/"),concat(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(lower(col('TITLE')),r'[^a-z0-9\s]',''),r'\s','_'),lit(".png"))))
#error line ---filter----
bob_ross.filter(os.path.exists(col("image")))
print(bob_ross.head())
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of the code

Answer (score 0):

You should be using filter function, not an OS function

For example

```
df.filter("image is not NULL")
```

`os.path.exists` only operates on the local filesystem, while Spark is meant to run on many servers, so that should be a sign you're not using the correct function

Comment: but i have given the col url values even it may not exists, so "url is not NULL " could not be used

Comment: That column must exist... It's part of the dataframe. `os.path.exists` is not a Spark function. It does not accept a colum

Comment: Your error is the fact that you are trying to convert a local filesystem check into a distributed Spark execution. If you do `os.path.exist("/dbfs")`, then that will run *per Spark executor*, not just on a single machine like Pandas will